# Understanding sklearn's KNNImputer

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science, imputation

I was going through its documentation and it says

> Each sample’s missing values are imputed using the mean value from
>   n_neighbors nearest neighbors found in the training set. Two samples
>   are close if the features that neither are missing are close.

Now, playing around with a toy dataset, i.e.

```
>>>X = [[1, 2, nan], [3, 4, 3], [nan, 6, 5], [8, 8, 7]]
>>>X

   [[ 1.,  2., nan],
    [ 3.,  4.,  3.],
    [nan,  6.,  5.],
    [ 8.,  8.,  7.]]
```

And we make a KNNImputer as follows:

```
imputer = KNNImputer(n_neighbors=2)
```

The question is, how does it fill the `nan`s while having `nan`s in 2 of the columns? For example, if it is to fill the `nan` in the 3rd column of the 1st row, how will it choose which features are the closest since one of the rows has `nan` in the first column as well? When I do `imputer.fit_transform(X)` it gives me

```
array([[1. , 2. , 4. ],
       [3. , 4. , 3. ],
       [5.5, 6. , 5. ],
       [8. , 8. , 7. ]])
```

which means for filling out the `nan` in row 1, the nearest neighbors were the second and the third row. How did it calculate the euclidean distance between the first and the third row?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How does it fill the `NaN`s using rows that also have `NaNs`?

This doesn't seem to be mentioned in the docs. But by digging a bit into the source code, it appears that for each column being imputed, all *donors* at a smaller distance are considered, even if they have missing values. The way this is handled is by setting to `0` the missing values in a weight matrix, which is obtained according to the used distance, see [`_get_weights`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/95d4f0841d57e8b5f6b2a570312e9d832e69debc/sklearn/neighbors/_base.py#L64).

The relevant code is in [`_calc_impute`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/95d4f0841d57e8b5f6b2a570312e9d832e69debc/sklearn/impute/_knn.py#L110), where after finding a distance matrix for all potential donors, and then the above mentioned matrix of weights, it is imputed as:

```
# fill nans with zeros
if weight_matrix is not None:
    weight_matrix[np.isnan(weight_matrix)] = 0.0
```

Where all potential donors are considered if they have at least one non-nan distance with the *reciever*

```
dist_pot_donors : ndarray of shape (n_receivers, n_potential_donors)
    Distance matrix between the receivers and potential donors from
    training set. There must be at least one non-nan distance between
    a receiver and a potential donor.
```

We could check this with a toy example; in the following matrix, when inputting the missing value in `[nan,  7.,  4.,  5.]`, the last row (which also contains two `NaN`s) is chosen (note that I've set `n_neighbors=1`). This is because the distance wrt the last row is `0`, as the *distance* corresponding to the `NaN` values has been set to `0`. So by just having a minimal difference with rows `2` and `3`, the last row is chosen since it is seen as being equal:

```
X = np.array([[np.nan,7,4,5],[2,8,4,5],[3,7,4,6],[1,np.nan,np.nan,5]])

print(X)
array([[nan,  7.,  4.,  5.],
       [ 2.,  8.,  4.,  5.],
       [ 3.,  7.,  4.,  6.],
       [ 1., nan, nan,  5.]])

from sklearn.impute import KNNImputer
imputer = KNNImputer(n_neighbors=1)

imputer.fit_transform(X)
array([[1., 7., 4., 5.],
       [2., 8., 4., 5.],
       [3., 7., 4., 6.],
       [1., 7., 4., 5.]])
```

Comment: Can you explain "by just having a minimal difference with rows 2 and 3, the last row is chosen since it is seen as being equal"?

Comment: So if you notice, the last row and first only share the last colum. Since the rest of values in the las row are nan. And still it is the row used to replace the first row. That is because there is 0 difference. Nans are seen as 0 difference. While rows two and three, die have some error, minimal error but they are different. So the one with minimal error is chosen @arghhjayy

Comment: Understood. Now, say imputing row 1 column 1 nan was the first step. For the second step, we want to replace the nan in row 4 column 2. Then, for step 2, what will be the value at row 1 column 1, will it be a nan or the imputed value in the first step?

Comment: NaNs are filled column by column, as you can see in [`process_chunk`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/95d4f0841d57e8b5f6b2a570312e9d832e69debc/sklearn/impute/_knn.py#L235). So since the nan in the first row is at the left, it will already have been imputed, so the new value should be considered if I'm not missing something @arghhjayy

Answer (score 1):

### The `nan_euclidean_distance`

The kNNImputer in `sklearn` uses the `nan_euclidean_distance`. You can find the doc here on Sklearn: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.nan_euclidean_distances.html

It a nutshell, it uses only available features to compute a pseudo Euclidean distance. This way, even observations with missing values can have their distance computed to other observations.